# Create table in SQL Server using union

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In mysql we write query as

```
create table new_table as (select a.* from Table1 a union select b.* from Table2 b)
```

This syntax doesn't work in SQL Server - what's the way around for creating a table from union in SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `SQL Server`, you can use `SELECT .. INTO`

```
 select a.* 
 into   new_table
 from   Table1 a 

 union 

 select b.* 
 from   Table2 b
```

Answer (score 3):

The following query should do what you want:

```
select * into new_table
from (
select * from Table1 union select * from Table2 ) a
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your query as shown below for creating table in sql server using union clause.

```
create table #table1 (Id int, EmpName varchar(50))
insert into #table1 values (1, 'Suraj Kumar')

create table #table2 (Id int, EmpName varchar(50))
insert into #table2 values (2, 'Davinder Kumar')

SELECT * INTO #NewTable FROM 
(SELECT Id, EmpName FROM #table1
UNION
SELECT Id, EmpName FROM #table2
)a

SELECT * FROM #NewTable
```

Here new table of name - #NewTable has been created by union of two tables #table1 and #table2

Comment: will it work if I use * rather than specifying columns